# Returning self from a function to conform the protocol UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I've got stuck with the development of my new app. I was hoping, that somebody could help me, to solve the problem. I'd be very glad ;)

Currently I'm trying to display an alert for a notification object, which is getting triggered by the `UNUserNotifictionCenter`. The alert is getting  shown, when you leave the app and the trigger is fired, but as soon as you are working in the app and the alert should be triggered nothing will happen. To do so, you have to adopt the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, which can display an alert for the notification object. There is where I got stuck.

The `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` inherits form the `NSObjectProtocol`, which requires a function called `'self'()`, the implementation of that function also returns a value, which should be of the type `self`.

To return this requested self I've tried two options:

```
func `self`() -> Self {
    var delegate = type(of: self)
    //delegate = type(of: self).self
    return delegate
}
```

And the other option, with the thread style:

```
func `self`() -> Self {
    var delegate = NSObject().value(forKey: Thread().name!) as! Self
    return delegate
}
```

None of the both options seams to work. So I'd be very thankful if some one could give me a helping hand with this.

Greetings Javed

Answer (score 2):

I think you would better **inherit** your class you want to be an `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` from `NSObject` like this

```
class MyUserNotificationCenterDelegate : NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

     // implementation
}
```

As it is known that `NSObject` implements `NSObjectProtocol`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If we would try your version, the complier would give an error, because an instance of your class is of type NSObject and not UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Have you tried it already, or you just think it would give an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your `AppDelegate` should conform to protocol `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to display notifications when the app is in foreground.

Simply add the following to your `AppDelegate` definition :

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
```

Now, you will need to add the following functions in your `AppDelegate` that confirms to this protocol

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler([.sound,.alert,.badge])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    //do whatever you want to here
    completionHandler()
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I get to it. I currently have some issues with my Mac Book. Hope that your solution will work ;) I'll let you guys know.